# ¿Cómo se deben poner las rutas a mis archivos de aplicación en ElectronJS cuando tengo activo asar?

Tags: nodejs, electron, electron-build

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio en ElectronJS que funciona bien cuando la empaqueto con **electron-builder** y opcion "build": { .... "asar": false,...}

Pero cuando hago el build con "asar": true obtengo una excepción **Error: Cannot find module**

Entiendo que no encuentra un archivo dentro de app.asar.

Ejemplo de mi ruta:

```
const workerURL = path.join(__dirname, 'login-worker.js')
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Encontré reportes de problemas similares, puedes ver todo el historial [aquí](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/issues/217)

Puedes intentar sustituir `devDependencies` por `dependencies` en `package.json`:

Esto no funciona (package.json)

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "jsonfile": "^2.4.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Esto funciona (package.json):

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "jsonfile": "^2.4.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Si eso no corrige el problema, en el reporte también mencionan que declarando las rutas de la siguiente forma puede funcionar

```
module.paths.push(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app', 'node_modules'));
module.paths.push(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app.asar', 'node_modules'));
```

Extrapolando ese ejemplo a tu caso, tal vez esto pueda funcionar

```
const workerURL = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'login-worker.js')
```

Por último, si esto tampoco funciona, intenta poner el `path` de la siguiente forma `"./login-worker.js"`

```
const workerURL = path.join(__dirname, './login-worker.js')
```

Comment: Gracias, aunque no me funcionaron ninguna de estas opciones. En la documentación oficial dice que se recomienda yarn en lugar de npm, así que estoy migrando hacia allá.

Comment: Gracias por la retroalimentación, voy a intentar encontrar más información, si encuentras la solución por favor responde tu propia pregunta y acéptala para así ayudar a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares